# Remove Bootloader on Arduinos

Tags: c, arduino, atmega, atmel

I am trying to move from arduinos to AVR C. Would somebody know how to remove the arduino bootloader from the microcontroller? Is there a different process for the different atmega microcontrollers like the 32u4, 328, or 2560?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AVR dude to erase the flash. This thread might help 
http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/how-can-i-erase-chip-using-avrdude

Answer (score 3):

The Arduino bootloader will be removed when you program the atmega using a programmer.

When you program Arduino using the Arduino bootloader it knows how to write to the image such that the bootloader is preserved.

When you create an image from AVR C and flash it to the atmega the image will overwrite the bootloader, when your atmega is next reset it will now run your image instead of the bootloader.

The process will be the same regardless of the part however your project will need to be set up appropriately.